# error en java al guardar imagen en mysql

Tags: java, mysql

en el siguiente codigo, el metedo insertDatos funciona perfectamente, pero el metodo editarDatos me esta dando dolor de cabeza, ya no le encuentro la vuelta

```
 public int insertDatos(String nom,String apell,String com,String
     pos,String emai,String tele,String not, FileInputStream[] fot)throws FileNotFoundException{

   int res = 0;
   File file = new File(ruta);
   // FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    try{
        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(QUERY_INSERT);
        PS.setString(1, nom);
        PS.setString(2, apell);
        PS.setString(3, com);
        PS.setString(4, pos);
        PS.setString(5, emai);
        PS.setString(6, tele);
        PS.setString(7, not);


        byte[] icono = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        input.read(icono);
        //PS.setFoto(icono);
        PS.setBytes(8, icono);



        res =PS.executeUpdate();


        if(res > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro guardado exitosamente");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error al guardar los datos en la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS=null;
        CN.close();
    }
    return res;

}

public int editarDatos(String id,String nom,String apell,String com,String pos,String emai,String tele,String not, FileInputStream[] fot) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String SQL = "update cliente set nombre='"+nom+"', apellido='"+apell+"', compañia='"+com
            +"', posicion='"+pos+"', email='"+emai+"', telefono='"+tele+"', notas='"+not+"', foto='"+fot+"' where id="+id;
   File file = new File(ruta);
    int res = 0;
    try{
       byte[] icono = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        input.read(icono);
        //PS.setFoto(icono);
        //PS.setBytes(8, icono);


        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
        res =PS.executeUpdate();
        if(res > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro editado exitosamente");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error al editar los datos en la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS=null;
        CN.close();
    }
    return res;

}
```

Tengo que igualar la variable icono a fot? para que me pueda guardar la imagen en mysql.
El metodo insertDatos incluso me guarda un archivo el cual soy capaz de abrir en phpmyadmin, pero, editar datos me guarda un archivo raro el cual no es igual en tamaño al original

todos los demas registros estan bien, pero, fot me sale mal

Por ultimo les dejo el codigo del metodo editar, en el cual llamo a una variable num la cual si es igual a cero es una entrada nueva y si es distanta a cero es una entrada a editar

```
 private void editar() throws IOException{

   // File file = new File(ruta);
    //FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

    String id = jtf_id.getText();
    String nom = jtf_nombre.getText();
    String apell = jtf_apellido.getText();
    String com = jtf_compañia.getText();
    String pos = jtf_posicion.getText();
    String emai = jtf_email.getText();
    String tele = jtf_telefono.getText();
    String not = jta_notas.getText();
    FileInputStream[] fot = new FileInputStream[(jtf_foto.getText().getBytes()).length];

    if (num == 0){

        int resp = insertDatos(nom, apell, com, pos, emai, tele, not, fot);
        if (resp > 0){
        verContactos();
        limpiarTF();
        }

    }else{
        int resp = editarDatos(id, nom, apell, com, pos, emai, tele, not, fot);
    if (resp > 0){
        verContactos();
        limpiarTF();
        num=0;

    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

En el método `editarDatos` no estás usando correctamente la consulta preparada. No entiendo por qué no implementas el mismo procedimiento que en `insertDatos`, a diferencia de que deberás pasar como último parámetro el `id` por se el último valor que se usa en el  `where`:

```
public int editarDatos(String id,String nom,String apell,String com,String pos,String emai,String tele,String not, FileInputStream[] fot) throws FileNotFoundException{
    String SQL = "update cliente set nombre=?, apellido=?, compañia=?, posicion=?, email=?, telefono=?, notas=?, foto=? where id=?";
   File file = new File(ruta);
    int res = 0;
    try{
       byte[] icono = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        input.read(icono);

        PS = CN.getConnection().prepareStatement(SQL);
        PS.setString(1, nom);
        PS.setString(2, apell);
        PS.setString(3, com);
        PS.setString(4, pos);
        PS.setString(5, emai);
        PS.setString(6, tele);
        PS.setString(7, not);
        PS.setBytes(8, icono);
        PS.setString(9, id);

        res =PS.executeUpdate();
        if(res > 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro editado exitosamente");
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error al editar los datos en la BD" + e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        PS=null;
        CN.close();
    }
    return res;

}
```

Comment: a ver, el metodo editarDatos toma los datos ya existentes, es decir, si voy a editar un registro, pues algo de ese registro debe existir, ejemplo, el nombre y apellido; cuando estoy editando lo que hago es seleccionar un registro y este automaticamente me llena los textfields con la informacion existente y cuando hago algun cambio pues, solamente le doy a guardar, el problema es que no me esta guardando la imagen, solo ese es mi problema, pero, voy a ver si con esta sugerencia me sale todo bien xDDD, muchas gracias por responder

Comment: @BarlyEspinal conviene que entiendas cómo funciona el `UPDATE` y quizá debas optimizar el código más adelante, para no tener que cambiar todas las columnas, sino solamente aquellas que cambien. En cualquier caso, el código no funcionaba porque estabas usando mal la consulta preparada. Si dices que en el `INSERT` funcionaba, debería funcionar también en el `UPDATE`.

Comment: acabo de probar tu sugerencia y no me resolvio el problema(es que soy novato en esto de java), pero, desde mi logoica el problema esta aqui FileInputStream[] fot = new FileInputStream[(jtf_foto.getText().getBytes()).length];     lo que quiero hacer con esta linea de codigo es que cuando elijo una imagen, en un textfield se queda la ruta del archivo y quiero usar esa ruta del archivo para convertirlo en bytes y poder guardar la foto en mysql. Todo funciona bien, a excepcion de la foto

Comment: He hecho estos cambios : File archivo = new File(jtf_foto.getText());   ///  archivo.getAbsolutePath().getBytes().length;     ////   byte[] fot = new byte[(archivo.getPath().length())];      se que estoy cerca, pero, estoy dando vueltas, muchas gracias por las sugerencias

Comment: ¿No dices que en la parte del `INSERT`  te funciona?  En cuanto al archivo he puesto el código del archivo tal y como lo tienes en la parte del `INSERT`, por lo tanto debería funcionar. Un `INSERT` y un `UPDATE` son prácticamente lo mismo, sólo que uno agrega los datos por 1ª vez y el otro los actualiza. Otra cosa es que en el `UPDATE` intentes con otra imagen que sea más grande por ejemplo y supere el tamaño máximo o algo así, entonces sí fallaría, @BarlyEspinal

Comment: me funcionan ambos xD, lo que pasa es k el editarDatos no me funciona el guardar imagen, creo k fue mi error por no exponer bien los datos, cuando edito una entrada lo hago desde el formulario que he creado, el cual tiene textField y desde ahi es k hago todo, lo que quiero es que el usuario no tenga que ver una sola linea de codigo para trabajar con esto.

Comment: La única diferencia que hay en el `UPDATE` es el `id` que se usa en el `WHERE`... Si ese `id` es numérico en la base de datos, entonces el parámetro que debes pasar ahí es un `int`, no un `String`. También debes revisar que todas las variables están llegando bien y que la consulta se cumple con el criterio. Todas esas cosas pueden hacer que el código no funcione, @BarlyEspinal