# Leer y mostrar imagen en Java

Tags: java, imagen, archivo

Mi intención es pedir una imagen, almacenarla en una base de datos como campo blob y mostrarla.
Para leer el archivo empleo el siguiente código:

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
jf.showOpenDialog(this);
File file = jf.getSelectedFile();
```

Para ser sincero, no tengo claro si es la mejor manera de pedir una imagen, y de serlo, no se como manejar un archivo para pasarlo a imagen y poder mostrarlo o pasarlo a la base de datos.

Tampoco tengo del todo claro que la mejor manera de almacenar una imagen sea en base de datos, por si alguien puede aclarármelo también.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [error en java al guardar imagen en mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/186981/error-en-java-al-guardar-imagen-en-mysql)

Comment: La mejor manera de almacenar una imágen es algo que hace que tu pregunta se base en opiniones, y así no funciona este sitio, posiblemente tu pregunta sea cerrada si no la haces más objetiva.